# How to have always one layer of indentation in interactive jupyter cells in VSCode for legibility reasons?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, format, indentation

For legibility reasons, I am used to work in interactive jupyter cells in VSCode for Windows with **one layer of indentation**, as shown in the following image in `%## cell 1`:

[image]

I like to do this because then I can collapse the cells I am not using and I can easily distinguish the code of each cell.

Recently, I was working like this and everything worked fine. However, from the last update on VSCode (1.68.0, 08-06-2022) I am getting the following error:

`IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Which if I remove the outer indentation it solves the problem.

**Question:** *Is there a way to configure VSCode to ignore the outer indentation and make it work as in the previous versions?*

In some previous versions I was having the same problem which I could make it work writing `if True:` at the start of the cell (see `%## cell 3`). However, I find this unnecessary and if there is an alternative I would prefer to not to use this method.

Comment: I tried to find such a configuration, but sorry I didn't. As you said, this should be a problem with the version update. I'm afraid you can only fix this by rolling back a version. Alternatively, you can submit this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) for official resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, here is the submit on the issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10443